# How create a service in linux that can handle queries?

Tags: systemd, services

I want to create a linux service and be able to communicate with it. Something like a database which I can add and get data. Is there any way to communicate with my service without making the service a server?
I mean do not use `http` or `https` methods to send and get data.
The thing that I want is a way to connect to the service without using a `URL` and `port` number.

Comment: If the problem is specific to the HTTP protocol, other options are available. For example [Docker uses various types of sockets for communication](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: When you say "except a URL and port number", do you mean "I want to use a URL/port" or "I don't want to use a URL/port"?

Comment: @Stewart I mean "I don't want to use a URL/port" , sorry for bad use of words!

Comment: How would you like to communicate with your service then?  Raw ethernet?  Serial port? Files?

Comment: @Stewart I'm not sure, I just know I have to write a service for an embedded device, such as raspberry. I have to be able to do some task with my own computer using this device. I think you'r answer can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is to use [systemd.socket](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html)

Let's say that I have any program which reads stdin and writes to stdout.  You can configure systemd to make that accessible via a socket.

Here's an example of how you'd configure systemd to do that:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/simple.socket
[Socket]
Accept=yes
ListenStream=11111

# /etc/systemd/system/simple@.service
[Unit]
Description="Simple service"
After=network.target simple.socket
Requires=simple.socket

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=-cat -
StanardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
```

Next start the socket with:

```
$ sudo systemctl start simple.socket
```

Now you can run the service by establishing a socket.  I use `nc` or `netcat` for this:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 11111
```

In `ExecStart` I choose to use `cat -` which simply relays stdin to stdout.  When we run `nc`, we will discover that whatever we type into stdin will be echoed back to us via stdout.  You probably have an application which is more interesting that you'll want to run.

A few other cool points:

- `cat` is not running if you don't have an open socket (the socket is listening but the service is stopped).
- When you establish a connection, the service starts
- If you establish another connection, another instance of the service starts.
- When you close a connection the service stops.

Comment: The question does say, and this is repeated a further twice in comments, that the questioner does not want to use a port number, and 11111 is definitely a port number here.  So it's a puzzle that this is the accepted answer.

Comment: I wrote this question before I saw there was an alternative way to interpret the question.  I asked in the comments and **then** edited the question to make it clear once I realized what he wanted.

Comment: That's not the puzzle.  That the questioner accepted an answer using port numbers is.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something is receiving connections, you have a server. HTTP/S is just one protocol of many, many. You can connect to a remote database by its own protocol also. If you are looking for a more complex solution, read about SSH tunnelling - forward and reverse. And `systemd` is in no way a required element in your solution.

Comment: the thing that I want is a way to connect to the service except a `URL` and `port` number.
is it more clear?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi You would need to use some very unusual network infrastructure to get that. And a tailored OS. Even localhost is a URL. Port can be default though.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi How do you want to access something without naming its address anyhow?

Comment: how a database works? I mean some thing like that

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Even something like that uses addresses...

Comment: Maybe a unix domain socket?

Comment: @jsbillings That's an address also.

Comment: @tom I agree, but I’m trying to give the OP more ideas to describe what they expect

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi : Mongodb is accessed through the URI `mongodb://myusername:mypassword@hostname.:identifier`; the mysql database is accessed through `mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database`, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access this on your local machine only, and you want to make simple scripts, use a fifo. If you want other systems on the network to have access as well, look at netcat (`nc`).

For Python adepts, there is Flask, and for Perl programmers, Dancer2.

In C, you would use `socket`, `bind` and `listen`.

And as @tom remarked: `systemd` has nothing to do with what you're asking for.

EDIT:

Your addition

> The thing that I want is a way to connect to the service except a URL and port number.

makes it completely unclear what you are looking for.

If you want to communicate with a computer, you must know its address. Otherwise, you will never know who you are communicating with. Your database and your client must also have an agreed protocol. Otherwise they will not understand each other. And with that, you have by necessity a URI.

If you do not want to use a port number, like TCP or UDP does, you can use another protocol (https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) if that suits you. 253 or 254 would then be suitable. But, and please do not take this as patronizing, you do not seem to have the skill yet  to make this working.

If you would take recommendations, try to use a fifo on the same system first. If that works, investigate in netcat.

Comment: I'm not communicating with a computer on network, it's all in my device. I run a service on my device and communicate on my device.

Comment: Since the questioner has said "how a database works", perhaps answers could suggest things based on the ways in which databases indeed do work, including `AF_LOCAL` sockets.  The idea of a named FIFO is somewhat buried at the end of this answer.